# Dynamically Creating Routes in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

We're trying to make the switch to angular, but we have a pretty big issue with routing. Our current site has something like 10,000 unique routes -- ever page has a unique ".html" identifier. There's no particular convention that would allow us to assign the controller to them, so I created a lookup API endpoint.

**Here's the workflow I'm trying to create:**

- Angular app loads. One "otherwise" route is set up.
- When someone clicks a link, I don't know if the resource is a product or a category, so a query is made to the lookup endpoint with the unique ".html" identifier. The endpoint returns two things: the name of the resource, and an ID ("product" and "10" for example). So to be clear, they hit a page like, "http://www.example.com/some-identifier.html," I query the lookup API to find out what kind of resource this is, and get a result like, "product" and "10" -- now I know it's the product controller/template and I need the data from product id 10.
- The app assigns the controller and template ("productController" and "product.html"), queries the correct endpoint for data ("/api/product/10"), and renders the template.

**The problems I'm facing:**

- $http isn't available during config, so I can't hit the lookup table.
- Adding routes after the config is sloppy at best -- I've done it successfully by assigning $routeProvider to a global variable and doing it after the fact, but man, it's ugly.
- Loading all the routes seems impractical -- just the size of the file would be pretty heavy for a lot of connections/browsers.
- We can't change the convention now. We have 4 years of SEO and a lot of organic traffic to abandon our URLs.

I feel like I might be thinking about this the wrong way and there's something missing. The lookup table is really the problem -- not knowing what kind of resource to load (product, category, etc). I read [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs) about loading routes dynamically, but again, he's not making an external query. For us, loading the controllers isn't the problem, it's resolving the routes and then assigning them c

How would you solve the problem?

## Solution


*Huge thanks to @user2943490 for pointing me in the right direction. **Don't forget to upvote his answer!** I made it a little more general so that I don't have to define the route types.*

**API Structure**

This configuration requires at least two endpoints: `/api/routes/lookup/:resource_to_lookup:/` and `/api/some_resource_type/id/:some_resource_id:/`. We query the lookup to find out what kind of resource it points to and what the ID of the resource is. This allows you to have nice clean urls, like, "http://www.example.com/thriller.html" (a single) and "http://www.example.com/michaeljackson.html" (a collection).

In my case, if I query something like, "awesome_sweatshirt.html" my lookup will return a JSON object with "{type: 'product', id: 10}". Then I query "/api/product/id/10" to get the data.

"Isn't that slow?" you ask. With varnish in front, all of this happens in way less than 1 second. We're seeing pageload times locally of less than 20ms. Across the wire from a slow dev server was closer to half a second.

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute'
])

.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
    .otherwise({
        controller: function($scope, $routeParams, $controller, lookupService) {
            /* this creates a child controller which, if served as it is, should accomplish your goal behaving as the actual controller (params.dashboardName + "Controller") */
            if ( typeof lookupService.controller == "undefined" )
                return; 

            $controller(lookupService.controller, {$scope:$scope});
            delete lookupService.controller;
            //We have to delete it so that it doesn't try to load again before the next lookup is complete.
        },        
        template: '<div ng-include="templateUrl"></div>'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})

.controller('appController', ['$scope', '$window', '$rootScope', 'lookupService', '$location', '$route', function($scope, $window, $rootScope, lookupService, $location, $route){

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', handleUniqueIdentifiers);

    function handleUniqueIdentifiers (event, currentUrl, previousUrl) {
        window.scrollTo(0,0)

        // Only intercept those URLs which are "unique identifiers".
        if (!isUniqueIdentifierUrl($location.path())) {
            return;
        }

        // Show the page load spinner
        $scope.isLoaded = false  

        lookupService.query($location.path())
            .then(function (lookupDefinition) {
                $route.reload();
            })
            .catch(function () {
                // Handle the look up error.
            });
    }

    function isUniqueIdentifierUrl (url) {
        // Is this a unique identifier URL?
        // Right now any url with a '.html' is considered one, substitute this
        // with your actual business logic.
        return url.indexOf('.html') > -1;
    }
}]);
```

**lookupService.js**

```
myApp.factory('lookupService', ['$http', '$q', '$location', function lookupService($http, $q, $location) {
    return {
        id: null,
        originalPath: '',
        contoller: '',
        templateUrl: '',
        query: function (url) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var self = this;

            $http.get("/api/routes/lookup"+url)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                self.id = data.id;
                self.originalPath = url;
                self.controller = data.controller+'Controller';
                self.templateUrl = '/js/angular/components/'+data.controller+'/'+data.controller+'.html';
                //Our naming convention works as "components/product/product.html" for templates
                deferred.resolve(data);
            })

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}]);
```

**productController.js**

```
myApp.controller('productController', ['$scope', 'productService', 'cartService', '$location', 'lookupService', function ($scope, productService, cartService, $location, lookupService) {

    $scope.cart = cartService

    // ** This is important! ** //
    $scope.templateUrl = lookupService.templateUrl

    productService.getProduct(lookupService.id).then(function(data){
        $scope.data = data
        $scope.data.selectedItem = {}
        $scope.$emit('viewLoaded')
    });

    $scope.addToCart = function(item) {
        $scope.cart.addProduct(angular.copy(item))
        $scope.$emit('toggleCart')
    }

}]);
```

Comment: how many types of resources do you have? Do you have a controller for each type? i.e. a productController for product, a categoryController for category, etc...

Comment: @user2943490 Yep -- I'd say we have about 10 types of resources, but product and category are the big ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this.

In the route config you set up a definition for each resource type and their controllers, templates and a resolve:

```
$routeProvider.when('/products', {
    controller: 'productController',
    templateUrl: 'product.html',
    resolve: {
        product: function ($route, productService) {
            var productId = $route.current.params.id;
            // productService makes a request to //api/product/<productId>
            return productService.getProduct(productId);
        }
    }
});
// $routeProvider.when(...
// add route definitions for your other resource types
```

Then you listen for `$locationChangeStart`. If the URL being navigated to is a "unique identifer", query the lookup. Depending on the resource type returned by the lookup, navigate to the correct route as defined above.

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', handleUniqueIdentifiers);

function handleUniqueIdentifiers (event, currentUrl, previousUrl) {
    // Only intercept those URLs which are "unique identifiers".
    if (!isUniqueIdentifierUrl(currentUrl)) {
        return;
    }

    // Stop the default navigation.
    // Now you are in control of where to navigate to.
    event.preventDefault();

    lookupService.query(currentUrl)
        .then(function (lookupDefinition) {
            switch (lookupDefinition.type) {
                case 'product':
                    $location.url('/products');
                    break;
                case 'category':
                    $location.url('/categories');
                    break;
                // case ...
                // add other resource types
            }
            $location.search({
                // Set the resource's ID in the query string, so
                // it can be retrieved by the route resolver.
                id: lookupDefinition.id
            });
        })
        .catch(function () {
            // Handle the look up error.
        });
}

function isUniqueIdentifierUrl (url) {
    // Is this a unique identifier URL?
    // Right now any url with a '.html' is considered one, substitute this
    // with your actual business logic.
    return url.indexOf('.html') > -1;
}
```

Comment: Oh that I only have one upvote to give. Thanks a ton. We made it a bit more general and it's fantastic. I added the complete, more generalized solution to the question to help others who might be in a similar spot. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $[routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) for this.

e.g.

```
route/:type/:id
```

so type and id can be totally dynamic, the different type handling will be up to the route's controller.

Comment: That's not really the problem. Our URLS are more like, "http://www.example.com/some-identifier.html" and we don't know if that's a product page or a category. That's why I created the lookup service -- I query the API with "some-identifier.html" and it returns, "product" and "10" so that I know I need the product controller and the data from product id 10.

Answer (score 0):

What if you have a json file with the information of the routes (and if there is not a security issue) and iterate over it to attach routes to the app?

e.g.

JSON:

```
routes: [
{ 
  controller: "Controller1"
  path: "/path1"
  templateUrl: 'partials/home/home.html'
},
{ 
  controller: "Controller1"
  path: "/path1"
  templateUrl: 'partials/home/home.html'
}   
]
```

And then iterate over the contents of the JSON and attach them to `$routeProvider.when` ?
I am not sure if it is a good idea, depends how big would be the JSON file and if you dont want to expose all your routes to a possible attacker.

Comment: Exposing the routes isn't an issue, and the JSON file is a solution, but the file would be HUGE and the initial page load would be pretty terrible. That's why I created the lookup endpoint -- just to get the one we need.

Comment: @SeamusJames I think your solution with the endpoint is the best that you can have in this case, since you cannot change the routes because of SEO.

Comment: The problem is I can't get it to work -- I can't dynamically create a route after the page is loaded, once I've figured out what the resource is. That's the problem.

Comment: @SeamusJames maybe you can get the path from your endpoint and use `window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com/thepath";` instead of angular's routes. But that is messing the things even more.

Answer (score 0):

From [the AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams),

> The $routeParams service allows you to retrieve the current set of
>   route parameters.
>
> Dependencies: `$route`

Example look like

```
// Given:
// URL: http://server.com/index.html#/Chapter/1/Section/2?search=moby
// Route: /Chapter/:chapterId/Section/:sectionId
// Then
$routeParams ==> {chapterId:'1', sectionId:'2', search:'moby'}

ngRouteModule.provider('$routeParams', $RouteParamsProvider);

function $RouteParamsProvider() {
  this.$get = function() { return {}; };
}
```